# Auto-registration with a RegistrationSource in Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-3.1

Here's what I'm doing so far (code simplified):

```cs
public class MyRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public MyRegistrationSource(ContainerBuilder builder /*,...*/)
    {
       // ...
       this.builder = builder;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
        Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        // Some checks here
        var interfaceType = serviceWithType.ServiceType;
        var implementorType = FindTheRightImplementor(interfaceType);

        if (myRegisterConditionSatisfied) 
        {
            return Register(implementorType, interfaceType);
        }

        return Empty;
    }

    private IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> Register(Type concrete, Type @interface)
    {
        var regBuilder = builder.RegisterType(concrete).As(@interface).IfNotRegistered(@interface);
        return new[] { regBuilder.CreateRegistration() };
    }
}
```

Then, at startup I'm doing something like

```cs
builder.RegisterSource(
    new NonRegisteredServicesRegistrationSource(builder/*, ...*/));
```

The above is intended to register those matching services only when there's no previous registration. I tried doing the registration without using the `ContainerBuilder` but couldn't get it to work.

This is working but are there any issues in passing-in the `ContainerBuilder` instance to the `RegistrationSource`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably argue against passing in a `ContainerBuilder`.

Every type you register in your source will add a callback to a list of callbacks inside the Container Builder which will never get cleared, potentially creating a memory leak.

I'd suggest calling the static method `RegistrationBuilder.ForType` instead, which will give you a fluent builder and should let you subsequently call `CreateRegistration` as you are now.

You can see some pretty good examples of how do this in our [Moq integration](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.Moq/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extras.Moq/MoqRegistrationHandler.cs#L106-L132):

```cs
var reg = RegistrationBuilder.ForType(concrete)
                             .As(@interface)
                             .CreateRegistration();
```

Also, I don't believe `IfNotRegistered` will have any effect when used outside the context of a `ContainerBuilder`. You should use the provided `registrationAccessor` parameter to the registration source to look up a `TypedService` to see if it has already been registered:

```cs
var isRegistered = registrationAccessor(new TypedService(@interface)).Any();
```

Comment: Thank Alistair! **Memory leak** was the main reason I asked the question.

Comment: The key part is `registrationAccessor(new TypedService(@interface)).Any()`. Before passing the `ContainerBuilder` I was using `registrationAccessor(service /*arg to RegistrationsFor*/).Any()` which sometimes lead to an error.